# How to design around an opto-isolator

Tags: pcb-design, opto-isolator

I want to control another circuit that is completely isolated from the ESP32. I decided to use an optoisolator. Both the ESP32 and the second control board are powered by 3.3V but they are independent power supplies.

From the datasheet, it has a forward current of 20mA and a max forward voltage of 1.7V. Hence I used a 100-ohm resistor on the ESP32.

For the second control board, I just pulled up the Vo using a 1-kilo ohm resistor.

[image]

[image]

Datasheet: [6N137](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84732/6n137.pdf)

**I want if the below circuit is correct and what else can be improved to make it an industry design?**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN6e3J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to isolate my output from the ESP32 to the second device.

Comment: You don’t need to run the led at 20mA. What is the gpio current spec for the ESP32?

Comment: @Kartman around 40mA per the datasheet

Comment: In fact, you *shouldn't* run the LED at 20 mA. That's the absolute maximum rating, you should always operate well below the absolute maximum. The recommended operating conditions are to use a forward current between 5 and 15 mA, so I'd say go with 5-7 or so.

Comment: Note that **recommended operating conditions** suggest that a \$V_{CC}\$ supply voltage should be minimum of +4.5V. Your +3.3V is outside this limit. So your work to validate proper operation becomes a significant effort.

Comment: That's a really old part, and as mentioned you're using it at reduced \$V_{CC}\$.  There's parts out there _designed_ for 3.3V operation -- I'd suggest you do some shopping and find one.  Using a 5V part on 3.3V often works -- and when it doesn't, it comes as a surprise of the "car dead in a snowstorm" sort.  You'll spend less effort just finding a 3.3V part than you will fiddling with making a 5V part work.

Comment: An ADuM1281 or similar logic isolator might be better. It works on 3-5.5 VDC and has less than 3 nS rise/fall time. But they aren't cheap. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/ADUM1281BRZ-RL7/3542878

Comment: @PStechPaul that lead time though lolololol.....

Comment: @PStechPaul https://www.digikey.co.za/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/ISO7310FCD/6571987. This will work just as well :)

Comment: @PStechPaul that device has an inverted truth table compared to the 6N137. Always check the detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look carefully at this highlighted table from the data sheet in your question: -

[image]

Your MCU rail is 3.3 volts. Do you see the problem? This is the main showstopper.

You also need to have \$V_{ENABLE}\$ tied to \$V_{CC}\$. Secondary showstopper.

Please use 10 mA for the anode current (R1 = 220 Ω).

Comment: If the supply is 3.3 volts and the LED drops 1.1 to 1.7 volts, the 100 ohm resistor will drop 2.2 to 1.6 volts, so I(f) would be 22 to 16 mA. 150 ohms should be OK. There will also be some voltage drop from the ESP32.

Comment: @PStechPaul no, not on the LED side, on the MCU side <--- the MCU is running from 3.3 volts and that side of the opto needs 5 volts for it to work.

Comment: @JoeyB the side of the opto that connects to U3 needs 5 volts. U3 runs from 3.3 volts hence, trying to power that side of the opto from 3.3 volts IS NOT going to work. As I said in my earlier comment to PStechPaul **"*no, not on the LED side*"**

Comment: @Andyaka I see. I found another IC that works for that range ISO7310FCD https://www.digikey.co.za/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/ISO7310FCD/6571987

Comment: *"You also need to have V_ENABLE tied to VCC. Secondary showstopper."* Not necessarily. The truth table in Page 2 of the datasheet clearly shows the ENABLE pin is allowed to float as NC, and the output behaves as if the chip is enabled. Furthermore in Page 6, many parameter test circuits showed a floating ENABLE pin. Thus, I wouldn't say it's "wrong" to float it (though it's still the best practice to connect this pin for noise immunity).

Comment: @JoeyB that new device looks like it will work on your 3.3 volt rail. Have you checked that it has the same signal polarity i.e. it inverts like the 6N137?

Comment: I don't think it does have the correct polarity in the truth table @JoeyB

Comment: @Andyaka The inversion is not an issue. This is not going to be used for high-speed applications. It may toggle after a few hours or after a few days. Which I can accommodate in software

Comment: Then it should be OK if you can live with the inversion @JoeyB

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing any details about U3, I would say to increase R1 to 220 ohms, and increase R2 to something in the 4.7K to 10K range.  A higher resistance slightly increases the inputs susceptibility to external noise, but lowers the circuit's battery drain and reduces stress on the 6N137's output stage.

Answer (score 1):

R1 could be larger and still meet ratings; this saves some power consumption, and doesn't seem to have any impact on performance.  Anything 100-390Ω seems fine, as shown.

Conversely, R2 affects risetime, with smaller values giving faster output (and better noise immunity).  If you don't need the speed, a larger value can be chosen, saving some power consumption again.

I recommend a pull-up, or hard tie, from Ve to Vcc; the logic suggests there is an internal pull-up, but a value is not given.  (Current is given, which seems to suggest a constant current source instead of a pullup resistor, interestingly enough.)  Given the high CMRR this device offers, leaving a pin floating seems a little silly.